# how to disallow docker cp option

Tags: docker

I have a created a docker image for my running environment.

for some reason I need to put some encryption keys in the container since it requires it for it's operation .

is there some way I can block the option to execute docker cp and pull those keys?

thanks

Comment: how about encrypting them and reading them at runtime from memory

Comment: please explain? where would I keep those keys?

Comment: keep the encrypted one in image - which can be decrypted and moved the tmpfs at runtime (one can still copy if one knows the location inside the container) or read from the memory say like bash variable (if one knows the name one can use docker exec at runtime and print the value). So you can ask for decryption key at runtime - when container runs it'll ask for this first. [haven't used user input from ENTRYPOINT script - but should work normally when docker run is with -ti (terminal+interactive) options] - but you'll have to handle this in code for using it for TLS/SSL/smthng similar

Comment: Or why don't you execute the package only if authenticated with some command-line argument?? - say ENTRYPOINT script manages authentication then does decryption on basis of that and then execute the decrypted section?? | don't know how one can manage this but there is something like docker-secrets (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)

Comment: regarding he first option , how will the encrypted key be decrypted? who will decrypt it? if I use and environment variable to hide the encryption key it will be visible via simple docker inspect command

Comment: need to be handled all via the script in ENTRYPOINT

Answer (score 0):

No.

Docker doesn't have any way to selectively limit which commands a user can run.  Also, if you can `docker run` anything at all, you can, for instance, put yourself in the host's `/etc/sudoers` file and start poking around in `/var/lib/docker` for `*.key` files: anyone who can run Docker commands has unrestricted root access to the host.

Comment: is there a way of putting it as a environment variable  without showing in docker inspect command?

Comment: A privileged user on the host will be able to see every process's environment.  If your concern is around malicious users that could potentially run `docker cp`, then an environment variable is not "safe" regardless of whether or not `docker inspect` shows it.